# Can you solve this Riddle?

Tags: riddle

What comes once in a minute, twice in a moment but never in a thousand years?

Comment: flagging this as duplicate, sorry. @user56725 please check other questions for duplicate before you post. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> the letter m: **m**inute, **m**o**m**ent, no m in "a thousand years"